How to create this mesh deformation animation?
I'd love to know how this mesh deform animation is done, any ideas? Thanks in advance!
Source: https://lusion.co


I think you'd should be asking that question at blenderartists.org rather than here!

I don't know how it's done on the website. In Blender, you could use a rectangle curve and hook the control points to empties to get a similar effect.
